# Pretty-print with awk?

Tags: bash, awk, pretty-print

I have a code which is intended to output numbers stored in a file (which are in one column) to another TXT file. The part of the code which does this this is:

```
awk -F"\n" 'NR==1{a=$1"    ";next}{a=a$1"    "}END{print a}' col_trim.txt >> row.txt
```

the output is something like this:

```
1.31    2.3    3.35    2.59    1.63
2.03    2.21    1.99    1.5    1.12 
1    0.6    -0.71    -2.1    0.01
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
1.31    2.30    3.35    2.59    1.63
2.03    2.21    1.99    1.50    1.12 
1.00    0.60   -0.71   -2.10    0.01
```

As you see all numbers in the second sample have 2 digits after decimal and also if they are negative, the negative sign is placed before the number so it doesn't mess the arrangement of the numbers.

Any idea?

P.S.:
The input file is a text file with a column of numbers (for each row):

```
1.31
2.3
3.35
2.59
1.63
```

The whole code is like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

rm *.txt
for time in 00 03 06 09 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 39 42 45 48 51 54 57 60 63 66 69 72 75 78 81 84 87 90 93 96; do
    filename=gfs.t00z.master.grbf$time.10m.uv.grib2
    wgrib2 $filename -spread $time.txt
    sed 's:lon,lat,[A-Z]* 10 m above ground d=\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*:\1 '$time'0000:' $time.txt > temp.txt
    for (( j = 1; j <= 2; j++ )); do
        if [ j == 1 ]; then
            sed -n '/lon,lat,UGRD/,/lon,lat,VGRD/p' $time.txt > vel_sep.txt
        else
            sed -n '/lon,lat,VGRD/,/359.500000,90.000000/p' $time.txt > vel_sep.txt
        fi
        line=174305
        sed -n 1p temp.txt >> row.txt
        for (( i = 1; i <= 48;  i++ )); do
            sed -n "$line","$(($line+93))"p vel_sep.txt > col.txt
            sed 's:[0-9]*.[0-9]*,[0-9]*.[0-9]*,::' col.txt > col_trim.txt   
            awk -F"\n" 'NR==1{a=$1"    ";next}{a=a$1"    "}END{print a}' col_trim.txt >> row.txt
            line=$(($line-720))
        done
    done
done

exit 0
```

Comment: Can you show your input file?

Comment: Then your awk won't give the output as shown in question.

Comment: yes it will, it amends each row in every loop

Comment: Where are rows? that gives output like: `1.31    2.3    3.35    2.59    1.63`

Comment: As I said, the code is part of a loop. The contains of col_trim.txt are updated in every loop and then they are amended to the row.txt file with ">>" .

Comment: ok then did you try Jotne's answer?

Comment: No, cause I don't know how to apply it to a file. Jotne wrote the code for "echo" command

Comment: If you post your loop code as well then will be easier to understand for us.

Comment: Added on second time edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your awk by this:

```
awk -F"\n" 'NR==1{a=sprintf("%10.2f", $1); next}
           {a=sprintf("%s%10.2f", a,$1);}END{print a}' col_trim.txt >> row.txt
```

**EDIT:** For left alignment:

```
awk -F"\n" 'NR==1{a=sprintf("%-8.2f", $1); next}
           {a=sprintf("%s%-8.2f", a,$1);}END{print a}' col_trim.txt >> row.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much, By the way how can I shift the first column of numbers to the beginning of the line? I mean removing the spaces before first column

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work well enough, please check it out and see

Comment: I have actually tested that code before posting. Make sure you're also putting `-` in both `printf` functions as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `column` command:

```
awk -F"\n" 'NR==1{a=$1"    ";next}{a=a$1"    "}END{print a}' col_trim.txt | \
    column -t >> row.txt
```

This gives:

```
1.31  2.3   3.35   2.59  1.63
2.03  2.21  1.99   1.5   1.12
1     0.6   -0.71  -2.1  0.01
```

Comment: and how can I fix the format by two digits after decimal?

Comment: actually this is quick way to get a close solution. For the best results, use `printf "%7.2f", $1` in awk. See :http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using `printf` with `awk`

Eksample:

```
echo -e "1 -2.5 10\n-3.4 2   12" | awk '{printf "%8.2f %8.2f %8.2f\n",$1,$2,$3}'
    1.00    -2.50    10.00
   -3.40     2.00    12.00
```

Comment: Using the `f`. `%8.2f` gives `8` characters before `.` and `2` decimals. You need to post `col_trim.txt` for us to help to create a good `awk`.

Comment: I edited the question and show the template of col_trim.txt, it has a column of numbers as you can see.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, this script has big spaces we can improve.

Here is the first one:

change from:

```
for time in 00 03 06 09 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 39 42 45 48 51 54 57 60 63 66 69 72 75 78 81 84 87 90 93 96; do
```

to

```
for time in $(seq 0 3 96); do
    time=$(printf "%02d" $time)
```

if you can show us the sample output of `wgrib2 $filename -spread $time.txt`, we can give more suggestions.